# Why shared memory by MPI_Win_allocated_shared is not actually reachable by everyone?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, mpi, remote-access, shared-memory

I'm implementing an algorithm based on MPI parallel computation, but it also requires that all processes can access two shared buffers (ex two matrices arrays) whose contained data type is a user-defined class. MPI_Win_allocate_shared (which worked in my trials with array of doubles or simple class) doesn't work: one rank cannot actually see what other ranks write in the buffers, why??

```
std::pair <double, double> Options::BinomialPriceAmericanPut(void) {

int rank,size;
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

// shared buffers to save data for seller and buyer
MPI_Win win_seller, win_buyer;
// size of the local window in bytes
MPI_Aint buff_size;

// pointers that will (locally) point to the shared memory
PWL *seller_buff;
PWL *buyer_buff;

// allocate shared memory
if (rank == 0) {
    buff_size = (N+2) * (L+1) * sizeof(PWL);
    MPI_Win_allocate_shared(buff_size, sizeof(PWL), MPI_INFO_NULL,
                          MPI_COMM_WORLD, &seller_buff, &win_seller);
    MPI_Win_allocate_shared(buff_size, sizeof(PWL), MPI_INFO_NULL,
                          MPI_COMM_WORLD, &buyer_buff, &win_buyer);
}
else {
    int disp_unit;
    MPI_Win_allocate_shared(0, sizeof(PWL), MPI_INFO_NULL,
                          MPI_COMM_WORLD, &seller_buff, &win_seller);
    MPI_Win_allocate_shared(0, sizeof(PWL), MPI_INFO_NULL,
                          MPI_COMM_WORLD, &buyer_buff, &win_buyer);
    MPI_Win_shared_query(win_seller, 0, &buff_size, &disp_unit, &seller_buff);
    MPI_Win_shared_query(win_buyer, 0, &buff_size, &disp_unit, &buyer_buff);
  }

// up- and down- move factors
double u = exp( sigma * sqrt(expiry/N) );

// cash accumulation factor
double r = exp( R*expiry / N );
u= 1.2;
r=1.18;

// initialize algorithm
int p(size);
int n = N + 2; // number of nodes in the current base level
int s = rank * ( n/p );
int e = (rank==p-1)? n: (rank+1) * ( n/p );
// each core works on e-s nodes in the current level

// compute u and z for both seller and buyer: payoff (0,0) at time N+1
for (int l=s; l<e; l++) {
    const double St = S0*pow (u, N+1-2*l);
    const double Sa = St * (1+k);
    const double Sb = St * (1-k);

    // compute functions
    PWL u_s( {Line(-Sa, 0), Line(-Sb,0)} );
    PWL u_b( {Line(-Sa, 0), Line(-Sb, 0)} );

    // fill buffers
    seller_buff[l] = u_s;   
    buyer_buff[l] = u_b;
}

MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
// PROVE: here is where I get the error: position [4] is filled by rank 1
// and rank 0 gives a segmentation fault when trying to access it
if (rank==0) {
    std::cout << "PROVA: " << std::endl << "\tAsk = " << 
seller_buff[4].valueInPoint(0) << std::endl << "\tBid = " << - 
buyer_buff[4].valueInPoint(0) << std::endl;
}

// etc, freeing windows at the end
```

Here class PWL:

```
    #ifndef PWL_H_
#define PWL_H_

/* Class containing information about piecewise linear functions */

#include "Line.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

#define MINIMIZE_EPIGRAPH 0 // removes parallel lines keeping the one with highest intercept
#define MAXIMIZE_EPIGRAPH 1 // removes parallel lines keeping the one with lowest intercept


typedef std::vector<Line> lines_vector;

class PWL {
    friend PWL maxPWL (const PWL & f1, const PWL & f2);
    friend PWL minPWL (const PWL & f1, const PWL & f2);
    friend PWL operator/ (const PWL & f, double c);

    public:
        // vector of lines constituting the piecewise linear function
        lines_vector lines;
        // vector of abscissas of intersections among lines
        std::vector<double> x_intersections;

        // helper function giving the idx of the piece containing x
        size_t piece_of_interest (const double x ) const;

    public:
        // default constructor
        PWL () {
            lines.push_back( Line(0,0) );
            check_lines();
        }
        PWL (const int epi) {
            lines.push_back( Line(0,0) );
            check_lines(epi);
        }
        // constructor passing vector of lines: it computes x_intersections
        PWL (const lines_vector & v): lines(v) {
            check_lines();
        }
        PWL (const lines_vector & v, const int epi): lines(v) {
            check_lines(epi);
        }

        // evaluate function in a point
        double valueInPoint (const double x) const;

        // restrict function slopes within a given interval
        PWL restrict_slopes (const double l_bound, const double u_bound);

        // return the opposite of the piecewise linear function
        PWL opposite() const;

        // check if there are two consecutive parallel lines with different intercept
        // and compute x_intersections
        void check_lines (const int epigraph = MINIMIZE_EPIGRAPH);

        // getter
        lines_vector get_lines() const {return lines;}
        std::vector<double> get_intersections() const {return x_intersections;}

};

// maximum between piecewise linear functions
PWL maxPWL (const PWL & f1, const PWL & f2);
// minimum between piecewise linear functions
PWL minPWL (const PWL & f1, const PWL & f2);

// maximum between two lines in a given interval [a,b]
PWL maxLines (const Line & l1, const Line & l2, double a, double b);

// divide the function by a constant (operator overloading)
PWL operator/ (const PWL & f, double c);

#endif
```

Comment: The content of the `x_intersections` vector is very unlikely in the shared memory.

Comment: Why? Being simply a vector of double... do you have ideas about how to make it work?

Comment: If you know the max size, then declare it as an (fixed size) array instead of a (unknown size) vector.

Comment: Unfortunately I don’t know it, since the class model piecewise linear functions that can have whatever number of linear pieces